# Tensorflow debugger cannot work on windows 10

Tags: tensorflow

My code is fairly simple:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug

with tf.name_scope("multiplication"):
    a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    c = tf.div(a, b, name="mult")

    with tf.Session() as session:
        session = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(session)
        session.add_tensor_filter("has_inf_or_nan", tf_debug.has_inf_or_nan)
        session.run([ c],feed_dict={a:100, b:10})
```

But when I ran it:

```
>python test.py --debug 
... 
ImportError: No module named '_curses' 
... 
ImportError: No module named 'readline'`
```

I searched it online and found "_curses" is not supported on Windows 10. Does that mean I cannot use Tensorflow Debugger on Windows 10?

Answer (score 6):

According to: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger
You have to write in cmd the following:

```
pip install pyreadline
```

Answer (score 1):

I just verified TensorFlow 1.1.0 on a Windows Server 2016 Machine. tfdbg works. Here are the thing that I did, step by step

1. Install Anaconda 3 with python version 3.5
2. Open a command window as administrator.
3. "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe" install pyreadline
4. "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe" install  --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
5. Open Python shell with "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\python.exe"
6. In the Python shell, enter the following simple tensorflow code to launch a TFDBG terminal.

> ```
> import tensorflow as tf
> from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug
> a = tf.Variable(42.0, name="a")
> sess = tf.Session()
> sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)
> sess.run(a.initializer)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but cut and pasted the code listed above and got a different error from ui_factory.py as follows:

```
    ValueError: Exhausted all fallback ui_types.
```

Running Python 3.5.3, numpy 1.12.0, and TensorFlow 1.0.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: See my other answer above. This is because pyreadline is not installed. Please do ""C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip.exe" install pyreadline" (path may vary on your computer).

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow Debugger (tfdbg) is not fully functional in version 1.0.x. TensorFlow 1.1.0rc0 has just came out. Please try it out:

```
pip.exe install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.1.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

If there are still issues, please report them at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues

Also, it's perhaps worth pointing out the following:

1. The command-line interface of tfdbg is different between Windows and Linux/Mac. Windows does not have official `curses` support, so it uses the `readline` interface.
2. Because of 1., readline is a required dependency of tfdbg on Windows:

   pip.exe install pyreadline

Comment: I just verified that tfdbg from the latest release (1.1.0) works on Windows Server 2016. See my other answer above for detailed steps that I did.